# Responsive Web Design testing tool

Tags: android, html, css

Is it possible to reliably replace mobile phone with some testing tool as not to test with mobile? I 've tried Resizer and Responsive Design Bookmarklet, however I am not satisfied...
Thank you

Comment: Resize your browser(?)

Comment: Or use chrome with the developer tools

Comment: Try this tool http://www.bootstraputility.com/ this is the best tool i use recent time for testing my bootstrap and custom responsive designs.

Answer (score 1):

What LinkinTED said and Chrome also has options in their developer tools. If you press F12 and click in the settings icon, bottom right... Then go to Overrides.

There you can choose different sizes and user agents. Very handy.

Even BETTER than that is using Chrome Canary. They have a new feature called Emulation. I would recommend this the most. Just gotta download Chrome Canary.

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation

What's also really cool about this Canary feature is you can even test device pixel density. So that way if you ever do something to support "retina" displays, you can test it with that. I've used it when I made a website with a JavaScript plugin that would swap my images with @2x ones. So I didn't have to always upload it to a server and test it on a phone.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the [web developer addon for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/web-developer/).

Via resize > view responsive you can see the page in the following screen sizes:

- Mobile portrait (320x480)
- Mobile landscape (480x320)
- Small tablet portrait (600x800)
- Small tablet landscape (800x600)
- Tablet portrait (768x1024)
- Tablet landscape (1024x768)